# Force document.cookie update after creating new DOM element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

This is part of a much bigger project, but I've tried my best to simplify the problem I'm having. Here's the minimised situation:

1. Browser already stores cookie value `foo=bar` for domain `example.com` path `/`
2. Webpage `https://example.com/page` is loaded over HTTPS
3. After page load, an image is dynamically loaded using jQuery's `$("<img>", { src: "http://example.com/image" })`
4. The HTTP response from the server for `/image` includes a `Set-Cookie` header `foo=baz` for same domain and path, which is supposed to overwrite cookie from step 1
5. Webpage makes XHR to some other page
6. **The problem:** the request in step 5 is sent with the **old** cookie value `foo=bar`, not the `foo=baz` that was sent back with the image response

Upon a new page load, the new cookie value `foo=baz` is sent. The problem is that the browser's cookie store (and therefore `document.cookie`) only seems to be being updated at some point after my XHR. It's clearly being updated, since the new cookie value is being sent with new page loads, but isn't there at the time of my XHR.

I've tried using timeouts and [`waitForImages`](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) to ensure that the XHR occurs after the image has properly loaded. The image is also sent with the three response headers necessary to ensure it is never cached.

Some code that might better illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
$(function() {
  // document.cookie contains foo=bar (*)

  // The HTTP response for the /image contains a Set-Cookie for foo=baz
  $("<img>", { src: "http://example.com/image" }).waitForImages(function() {

    // The HTTP request for /some_other_page is sent with foo=bar, not foo=baz
    $.get("/some_other_page", function() {
      // ...
    });
  });
});

// if we reload the page, document.cookie contains foo=baz at the line marked (*)
```

Am I trying to do something that's impossible? Note that the URL in step 3 is being loaded over HTTP, not HTTPS, so XHR is not an option for this as the browser would block it. My question is this: **can I force document.cookie to be updated based on the response of the `<img>` tag I create in JavaScript?**

I've only tried this in Firefox 28.0. I need to get this working in all browsers though, so hopefully I can find a solution.

Sorry this has ended up being a bit long. Any advice greatly appreciated!